# Not able to Display the Text visible in the grayed out edit text in output

Tags: java, html, selenium

I m trying to display the visible texts from the grayed out edit boxes by using getText() method, but i am not getting any output. Can anyone kinldy help me out that how to display the text visible in the edit text.
Kindly find the screenshot below of the Edit text from which i want to display the text in the output of eclipse.

[image]

The HTML code for the Change Coordinator is given below

```html
<textarea class="text sr " wrap="off" id="arid_WIN_3_1000003230" cols="20" maxlen="69" style="top: 0px; left: 123px; width: 187px; height: 21px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" armenu="CTM:SGE:CABMgrAsg-CHG-Q" mstyle="2" arautoc="1" arautocmb="1" arautocak="0" arautoctt="400" arencryptdataatrest="0" rows="1" title="Shivhare, Siddhant 913896" readonly=""></textarea>
```

The java Code i am writing to display the Name Of the Change Coordinator

```js
String CoordinatorName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='arid_WIN_3_1000003230']")).getAttribute("title");
  System.out.println("The Co-Ordinator name is:- "+ CoordinatorName);
```

Comment: Have you tried `.getAttribute("value")`? That should work with a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that there is a change in frame.
Study the whole XML and see if there is a change in frame.

For example:

```
public void selectFrame(String toFrame) {
    driver.switchTo().frame(toFrame);
}
public void deSelectFrame() {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Comment: i have read the whole xml code, but i am not able to display on the Strings visible in the text fields, other than that i am able to display all the other strings visible on the screen.
Cant we use any other methods other than 'getText()' method as it was not working for my code.

Comment: As far as i know you have to use gettext() only and first select the frame and than you can gettext() .

Answer (score 0):

`getText()` will work on text embedded in the html. To get text from `<textarea>` (and `<input>` tags) you need to use `getAttribute("value")`

```
String coordinatorName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='arid_WIN_3_1000003230']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Or `getAttribute("innerHTML")`

```
String coordinatorName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='arid_WIN_3_1000003230']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: But there is no value tag available in the HTML tag, then how to use getAttribute() method

Comment: @AmitPandey Exactly as in my answer. The value attribute is not in the html, but it exists and holds the text.

Comment: but while i used this getAttribute() method with 'value' tag, i am not getting any value.
that is why I said that it does not exist

Comment: @AmitPandey You could also try `getAttribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: No this Tag name is also not giving any output.